# How to detect that a string contains character repetition longer than a 2-length sequence

Tags: python

Currently:

```
def detect_repet(s):
return_list=[]
    split_text= s.split('\n')
    print(split_text)
    for x in split_text:
        print(x)
    return

print(detect_repet('Well, sheep says beeeee and\ncat says miaaaaaaaw\nand cow would shout mooooooow'))
```

I am struggling with the detection of atleast two identical chracter in a row in a string: I've tried this but indexes overflow in later iterations:

```
my_string= "danieeeeel"
for i in range(len(my_string)):
    if(my_string[i]==my_string[i+1]==my_string[i+2]):
        print('YES')

    else:
        print('NO')
```

The ideal ouput of the detect_repet would be ['beeeee', 'miaaaaaaaw','mooooooow']

Answer (score 2):

I would use `re.findall` with the regex pattern `\b(\w*(\w)\2\w*)\b`:

```
inp = "Well, sheep says beeeee and\ncat says miaaaaaaaw\nand cow would shout mooooooow"
matches = [x[0] for x in re.findall(r'\b(\w*(\w)\2\w*)\b', inp)]
print(matches)  # ['Well', 'sheep', 'beeeee', 'miaaaaaaaw', 'mooooooow']
```

Note that your sample input string actually turned up two other words which repeat the same letter 2 or more times: `Well` and `sheep`.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop need to run till `len(my_string) - 2` to account for the index `i+2` which needs to be less than `len(my_string)` in the end.

You should also use a `set` to avoid duplicate results from longer runs of the same char:

```
def detect_repet(string):
    retval = set()
    for line in string.split():
        for i in range(len(line) - 2):
            if line[i] == line[i + 1] == line[i + 2]:
                retval.add(line)
    return retval


print(detect_repet('Well, sheep says beeeee and\ncat says miaaaaaaaw\nand cow would shout mooooooow'))
```

Result:

```
{'beeeee', 'miaaaaaaaw', 'mooooooow'}
```

Comment: You could add a break statement after `retval.add(line)` to skip the rest of the iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the list `line[i:i+3]` is composed of equal values using `set`s running for a loop `n-2` times because of the index `[i:i+3]` would be out of bounds:

```
def detect_repeat(string):
    retval = set()
    for line in string.split():
        for i in range(len(line) - 2):
            if len(set(line[i:i+3])) == 1:
                retval.add(line)
    return retval
```

or, with a set comprehension:

```
detect_repeat = lambda s:{line for i in range(len(line)-2) for line in s.split() if len(set(line[i:i+3])) == 1}
```

Output in either way:

```
{'miaaaaaaaw', 'beeeee', 'mooooooow'}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to add to @rdas's answer in terms of solving your specific problem. Still, on a didactical note, I'd like to point to `groupby` from the builtin `itertools` module. Whenever you need to group a sequence of elements `[a, a, a, b, b, b]` into chunks `[[a, a, a], [b, b, b]`, the first thing that comes to mind is `groupby`.

It generates `(label, subsequence)`-tuples you can iterate over. Since `subsequence` is a generator, you have to turn it into a list in order to calculate the length. With that in mind, another approach to your problem could be something like:

```py
from itertools import groupby

def detect_repet(s):
    for group in groupby(s):
        if len(list(group[1])) > 2:
            return True
    return False
```

This can be made even more concise and efficient, but it illustrates the idea.

You'd use it like this:

```py
>>> text = 'Well, sheep says beeeee and\ncat says miaaaaaaaw\nand cow would shout mooooooow'
>>> [word for word in text.split() if detect_repeat(word)]
['beeeee', 'miaaaaaaaw', 'mooooooow']
```